# XCTest not registering new methods as tests

Tags: xcode, xctest

I have a seemingly weird problem (unless I'm missing something totally obvious!) and am curious if anyone here has any insight. I've done quite a bit of searching and haven't found anything.

When I try and write unit tests in XCTest - creating new methods - they don't seem to register as tests and aren't executed when I run the test suite. They also don't get one of those nice little diamond run buttons next to them that allows you to run individual tests:
[image]

When using JUnit for example here you would annotate with @Test. Anything like this I'm missing?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Only method names that start with `test` are being recognized as tests. That way you can still use normal methods in your test classes that your actual test methods can call.

Comment: Sometimes you can seemingly run into this problem as well if the test case file isn't added to your test target

Comment: Even if your file is added to target, `uncheck` then `check` it again, should be happy now. :)

Answer (score 5):

#### Restart Xcode

New methods *starting with `test...`* were not being tested in my Test target.

```
- (void)testMethod {
    // not tested
}
```

Solution was to restart Xcode.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. My test methods already started with `test`, and target membership was already correct.  But restarting Xcode resolved my problem.

Comment: I think this ultimately solved my problem too, albeit in AppCode, not XCode. It didn't immediately register after restarting and took a while but finally the new test method I added is being recognized and is now individually runnable, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your new method must begin with "test", after add it , cmd + B, you will find your new method on your test navigator.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the test class in part of your test target.

Answer (score 0):

I had disabled indexing like this:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexDisable -bool true
```

setting it back to `false` and Xcode restart fixed it.