# Xcode Test Not Appearing in Test Navigator

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I just wrote a new test in my `XCTestCase` class. The original two default tests run perfectly. But for some reason Xcode isn't detecting the new test I just wrote.

It doesn't appear in the left side Test Navigator and doesn't appear in the Scheme test section.

How can I get Xcode to detect this new test so I can run it?

Comment: Are you sure the test method has a proper name?

Comment: @MichałMyśliwiec What do you mean?

Comment: All test methods must begin with `test` so e.g. `testForSomething`. I know it's obvious but it's worth to check. Another thing is that sometimes Xcode has an issue with indexing. Kill Xcode and launch again usually fix this.

Comment: @MichałMyśliwiec Actually never knew that. Not sure if I actually did that. Will check when I get to my computer.

Comment: @MichałMyśliwiec that worked!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Apple Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/defining_test_cases_and_test_methods)
A test method is an instance method on an XCTestCase subclass, with no parameters, no return value, **and a name that begins with the lowercase word test**. Test methods are automatically detected by the XCTest framework in Xcode.

Make sure your method has `test` at the start of the name.

Comment: And what if they are not automatically detected given all the listed criteria?

Comment: Shit, it is a Xcode bug. Please try with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/27783106/10158398

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me as well. The problem was my "ABCScreenTest" file was not  added to target membership to particular Test Suite. After adding them, the diamond appeared and file was testable. I am using Xcode 9.4.1. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a bug in Xcode 9. Try to create a new tab and see if the test is there.

You can also run the test by clicking the diamond next to the test in the editor.

Comment: No diamond appears on the left side in the editor. They do for the two original tests but not the new one. And not sure what you mean by new tap

Comment: Sorry, I mean tab. Cmd-t. Does the diamond appear when you save? Have you tried Xcode 8?

Comment: New tab doesn't work. Diamond doesn't appear when I save. And no I have not tried Xcode 8. If that's really the case I'll just wait for it to be fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Try to delete derived data and clean and restart Xcode.

Comment: Still didn't work

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. If you can (because of Swift version), try Xcode 8.

Comment: Happened to me on Xcode 9.4.

Comment: It occurs on Xcode 13.2.1 (13C100). The weird thing is that it only has this issue on simulator, when I use a real device, everything is fine.