# Xcode lost button test in xctest

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcode6, xctest

I working on Xcode 6. When I coding XCTest, Xcode has been crash. When I reopen my Xcode, and it lost little diamond run button.

It should be:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OGSn.png]

But it got:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpuD5.png]

I open other project and it don't have this error. But when I create new target, it get same error (in other project).

I checked Target Membership, but it checked in target name. When I choose Test in Product>Test it run but the button not show.

Thank a lot, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Try building, removing code and replacing it, and doing a clean build.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCTest not registering new methods as tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131579/xctest-not-registering-new-methods-as-tests)

Answer (score 9):

Prefix func name with **test**

Also try changing the targets

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1. Click on the test file (unit test or UI test file)
2. Go to right panel and you'll see `Target Membership`.
3. Select the Unit Test target and all would be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

There is two way to check it.

1. If you have multiple scheme, In top of Xcode, make sure you choose Test to run the test.

[image]

2. Click on your test class, then click right panel. In target membership, checklist the tests target.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In case you disabled indexing earlier,

1. Close all Xcode and Simulator instances
2. Delete this setting

   ```
   defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexDisable
   ```
3. Restart Xcode

This should reenable indexing and should bring back the individual test button (diamond shaped) in the subsequent Xcode launch.

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer for some - I had added a new scheme in Xcode, but the tests were only in the original scheme.  Switching back to the original scheme re-instated my tests.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was file was not included in the workspace. If not included, go to finder and drag and drop to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 12.4 just `Command+U` or menu `Product > Test` and all buttons in your `XCTestCase` will appear again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just re-started my Xcode and it worked. as everything was set-up the way it should be !!

Answer (score 0):

Prefix func name with **test**

example test function name:

```
 secondExample() must be **testSecondExample()**
```

then clean the build file
use this shortcut key **command + shift + k**

Answer (score -1):

Need More description?
But Try following troubleshooting...
check Target Membership of test file

Answer (score -1):

Go to,

Xcode > Window > Projects

click on the delete button for derived data. Close Xcode and open again. You should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Solution that is working for me in **Xcode 13**, **SWIFT 5**:

Open another Xcode file and then open the file wth your function again, the button should appear then.